# List into Dataframe

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
l = [{'County': 'SentenceCase'}, {'Postcode': 'UpperCase'}]
```

`type(l)` equals `<class 'list'>`

If I load it into a `dataframe`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

The first row then ends up as the column names.

```
         County   Postcode
0  SentenceCase        NaN
1           NaN  UpperCase
```

I've tried `Header=None`, etc. but nothing seems to work.

I would want the dataframe to be

```
   Header1   Header2
0  County SentenceCase        
1  Postcode UpperCase
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The first row isn't what ends up as column names. The keys in your dictionaries end up as column names.

Comment: {'County': 'SentenceCase'} were ending up as the column names. What I wanted to happen was the specify two column names rather than have them assumed from the first row of data.

Answer (score 0):

Every dictionary in the list represent a row in the table, the key is the Header.

It should look like that:

```
l = [{'Header1': 'County','Header2':'SentenceCase'},
{'Header1': 'Postcode ','Header2':'UpperCase'}]
```

Comment: LoL sorry missed clicked before finishing the post :P

Comment: It really is just that bit of code.

l = [{'County': 'SentenceCase'}, {'Postcode': 'UpperCase'}]

pd.DataFrame(l)

The list is the data I'm given, so I'd need to retrospectively somehow how to add the columns.

Comment: You can build a new List of dictionarys from your input list, and then call the `pd.DataFrame()` with the new list.

Comment: Yup. You'd think that would work.

x = [{'field': 'transform'}]+config['Transform']

Now x has the value: [{'field': 'transform'}, {'County': 'SentenceCase'}, {'Postcode': 'UpperCase'}]

and x has type: <class 'list'>

Yet, load x into a Datframe

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

and you end up with

       field        County   Postcode
0  transform           NaN        NaN
1        NaN  SentenceCase        NaN
2        NaN           NaN  UpperCase     [apologies that the comments remove all the returns making it pretty unreadable).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just using the wrong structure. instead of a list of dictionaries, you should have a list of lists to load into the DataFrame:

```py
[['County', 'SentenceCase'], ['Postcode', 'UpperCase']]
```

If for some reason you require your original structure, you could use something like this:

```py
new_l = []

for item in l:
    for key, value in item.items() :
        new_l.append([key, value])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_l)
new_df.columns = ['Header1', 'Header2']
new_df
```

which will give:

```
    Header1       Header2
0    County  SentenceCase
1  Postcode     UpperCase
```